# IE not showing PDFs with object tag correctly

Tags: html, pdf, internet-explorer, iframe, frontend

In my application I show pdf files. In order to do it, inside a html page I use object tag inside a div tag .

The problem is that the pdf viewer in IE8 is shown on top of all other components. In other words, the pdf file hides all popups, dialogs, etc...

anyone can helps thx!

```
<body>
  <div>
    <object data="abc.pdf" type='application/pdf'/>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: What version of IE?

Comment: Can you show us the code for your popups and dialog. Also inform us whether you can produce this issue with other browsers or not. We will try to make a test with it and try to produce the issue. Thanks for your understanding.

Comment: the problem is found at IE edge mode ,

Comment: From your last post, it looks like you had find the cause for the issue. I suggest you to post your solution as an answer and after 24 hrs mark it as an accepted answer for this question may help other community members in future in similar issues. Thanks for your understanding.